# Not connecting to Internet

Tags: 11.04, wireless, internet, hp

So I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop, and well it's not detecting any wireless connections, and what's even worse is that it won't connect to the internet via Ethernet cable. When I plug in the cable it says it's connected, but when I try using the internet it doesn't work. It says I'm connected though. I have a HP g7-1150uS.

Comment: Can you provide some information about how you know it's not connected to the internet, etc? What have you done?

Comment: Well I tried loading a few web pages such as Google, Youtube, and Yahoo. And they all failed to load, it just said No Connection where the webpage should have been. And when I look at the network manager it says connected by etho0. Also I have the 64 bit version of Ubuntu installed, idk if that is relevant or not.

Comment: What web browser are you using?  Do you have a proxy?

Comment: No proxy, and I'm using the default Firefox. Since I have no internet I cannot download any other browsers. the 32 bit version of Ubuntu also has this problem.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

You'll have to type your username and password you're using for internet connection.